# error in downloading the annotation of sequences on NCBI

Tags: r, ncbi

I have developed an R function to download the "organism" name of the numerous NCBI accession numbers which are already saved in an object.
The function:

```
get_organism_names <- function(accession_numbers) {
  organism_names <- sapply(accession_numbers, function(accession) {
    record <- entrez_summary(db = "nucleotide", id = accession)
    return(record$organism)
  }, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  names(organism_names) <- accession_numbers
  return(organism_names)
}
```

Although it works for some accession numbers, for others it encounters an error stating for example:

```
Warning: Esummary includes error message: Invalid uid KU253616.1 at position= 0Error: No esummary records found in file
```

How can I either solve this error or ask R to skip the problematic accession and keep downloading the rest?

Comment: Have you tried running it in a loop with a single accession each time instead of giving it all of them?

Comment: Also, please give us all of the code. Presumably, you are loading some libraries, which ones? We need example code that we can use to reproduce the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. We need example input, and then code that we can run locally that reproduces the error.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `tryCatch` [function](http://127.0.0.1:30714/library/base/html/conditions.html) to handle inputs that throw an error. A good example on how to write them can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r). Though the message indicates it's a warning, so does the function stop running when you get this message?